# Write a macro is_digit that returns true if its argument is a decimal digit

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to solve c++ practical programming.Here is the question.

Write a macro is_digit that returns true if its argument is a decimal digit.
Write a second macro is_hex that returns true if its argument is a hex digit (0-9 A-F a-f). The second macro should reference the first.

And here is my code. The problem is the macro is_digit is not returning 0 to digit_res when the input is not decimal digit.

Can anyone help me where I went wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define is_digit(x) (((x)=='0')||((x)=='1')||((x)=='2')||((x)=='3')||((x)=='4')||((x)=='5')||((x)=='6')||((x)=='7')||((x)=='8')||((x)=='9'))
#define is_hex(x) ((is_digit(x))||((x)=='a')||((x)=='b')||((x)=='c')||((x)=='d')||((x)=='e')||((x)=='f')||\
((x)=='A')||((x)=='B')||((x)=='C')||((x)=='D')||((x)=='E')||((x)=='F'))

int problem10_3()
{
string x;
int digit_res,hex_res;
cout<<"Enter Decimal or Hexadecimal:";
cin>>x;
digit_res=is_digit(x);
if(digit_res==1)
    cout<<"You have entered Decimal digit"<<endl;
else
{
 hex_res=is_hex(x);
 if(hex_res==1)
     cout<<"You have entered Hexadecimal digit"<<endl;
 else
     cout<<"You have not entered either Decimal or Hexadecimal"<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: dont use macros in c++. use inline functions

Comment: Macros don't "return" anything so you've failed at the first hurdle.

Comment: The problem is your counter-intuitive convention of using 0 to indicate "yes" and 1 to indicate "no".

Comment: You are passing the character `'x'` to your macros,and not a variable.

Comment: `s/counter-intuitive/polarly opposite to the stated requirements/`

Comment: Also, I believe you are missing a closing brace in the is_digit macro.  But, you don't need all of those comparisons since digits are consecutive ASCII characters.

Comment: `#define is_digit(N) isdigit(N)`

Comment: @nnn also makes a good point

Answer (score 3):

Well you literally have it backwards. You "return" `0` instead of `1`, and vice versa. No offence, but it's hard to see that as anything other than a silly typo.

Furthermore, you're "invoking" the macro with the character literal `'x'`, rather than any variable. You likely meant to either pass `&x[0]`, or read from *stdin* into a `char` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard library [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function, along with [`std::isxdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit) for hex, but if you really feel the need to write a macro, you can do so without a ternary or equality comparison

```
#define is_digit(x) ('0' <= (x) && (x) <= '9')
```

The use of the ternary is unnecessary

```
(a == b ? 1 : 0)
```

is the same as writing

```
(a == b)
```

If your goal here is compute the value at compile time then you should go with a constexpr function

```
constexpr bool is_digit(char x) {
    return '0' <= x && x <= '9';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have the logic of ? backwards

```
<condition> ? <if true> : <if false>
```

so do

```
#define is_digit(x) (((x)=='0')||((x)=='1')||((x)=='2')||((x)=='3')||((x)=='4')||((x)=='5')||((x)=='6')||((x)=='7')||((x)=='8')||((x)=='9'))?1:0
```

and as I said before - dont do macros in c++ - use inline functions

Answer (score 0):

as nnn said in a comment you have this too

```
digit_res=is_digit('x');
```

you mean

```
digit_res=is_digit(x);
```